# In same query MySql is possible to count row and get only the first row?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, mysqli

In same query `MySql` is possible to count row and get only the first row ?

Now i use this code (and i don't know if is correct):

```
$query1 = "
SELECT  magni
    FROM  earthquakes
    WHERE  (milli BETWEEN '$data_dal' AND '$data_al')
      AND  (magni BETWEEN '$magn_min' AND '$magn_max')
      AND  (ipoc BETWEEN '$ipo_min' AND '$ipo_max')
      AND  (lati BETWEEN '$lat_inf' AND '$lat_sup')
      AND  (longi BETWEEN '$lng_sin' AND '$lng_des')
    ORDER BY  magni DESC
    LIMIT  1";
$query2 = "
SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  earthquakes
    WHERE  (milli BETWEEN '$data_dal' AND '$data_al')
      AND  (magni BETWEEN '$magn_min' AND '$magn_max')
      AND  (ipoc BETWEEN '$ipo_min' AND '$ipo_max')
      AND  (lati BETWEEN '$lat_inf' AND '$lat_sup')
      AND  ((longi BETWEEN '$lng_sin' AND 180)
              OR  (longi BETWEEN -180 AND '$lng_des')
           )";

$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query1);
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
$array_statistiche = array($result2,$result1);  //numero eventi sismici, magniudo più alta

mysqli_free_result($array_statistiche);
$array_finale= $array_statistiche;

$array_terremoti= json_encode($array_finale); // return value of numero terremoti e array terremoti
mysqli_close($con); // close connection with database
```

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english !

Comment: You need two separate queries for this in MySQL, at least in versions earlier than 8+.  But, you could write the count query in the select clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about the duplication of effort in the bulky `WHERE`, then this is the clear winner:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS magni
    FROM earthquakes
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY  magni DESC
    LIMIT 1;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The first gets your one `magni`, then continues to scan the table to get the count.  The second gets that count in a thread-safe way.

`SELECT MAX(magni) ...` gets the desired single value without the `ORDER BY`.  But that won't help in this situation.

These indexes may help speed it up.  Only one with be used, but the Optimizer will pick which.

```
INDEX(magni),
INDEX(milli),
INDEX(lati)
```

If you really need to execute only a single query that returns both results, then consider:

```
SELECT
    ( SELECT MAX(magni) ... ) AS max_magni,
    ( SELECT COUNT(*)   ... ) AS ct;
```

That is, bury both bulky queries in a single `SELECT`.  You will be repeating the `WHERE` and performing the same scan twice.

Comment: for performance is better to execute two different query o one query?

Comment: @Borja - It depends on a lot of things.  Since there is overhead in sending a query to the server, 2 separate queries is likely to be slower than sending one complex query.  But I can't say "always".  My last example is _probably_ faster than 2 separate queries since the added complexity is not that much.

Comment: i used your last example and works very well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You need two separate queries to do this in MySQL versions less than 8+.  But, you can always add a subquery to the select clause of your limit query which finds the total count, something like this:

```
SELECT
    magni,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM earthquakes WHERE ...) AS cnt
FROM earthquakes
WHERE ...
ORDER BY magni DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I omitted some of your code partly because it doesn't affect the answer, and partly because I am not well versed in how to write a good statement in PHP. You should read about prepared statements in PHP, because it is generally bad practice to insert variables directly into your query string.

If you are curious, here is how we could phrase the above query in MySQL 8+ without using any subquery, using `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    magni,
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt
FROM earthquakes
WHERE ...
ORDER BY magni DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Here is a demo (in SQL Server, the closest match at the time of writing this answer) which shows this alternative in action.

### Demo

Comment: hmm i understand :) only one doubt what return this query (your first example) ? How can i add the different data (the count and the first item) like two different elements in php array ? i know that the question is about MySql but i want to understand like to use what the query return

Comment: Someone else can help you with the PHP, I just gave the structure of the query you might use here.